# OnClickListener doesn't work implicitly. Why?

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I created custom button class that implements listener interface:

```
public class BlinkButton  extends Button implements View.OnClickListener {

List<OnClickListener> onClickListenerList = new ArrayList<OnClickListener>();

public BlinkButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.setListener(new HighLightButtonListener());
}

//other constructors here 

public void setListener(OnClickListener listener){
    onClickListenerList.add(listener);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    for(OnClickListener listener : onClickListenerList){
        listener.onClick(this);
    }
}
```

And I have view:

```
   <com.example.element.BlinkButton
    .../>
```

I claim onClick method inside com.example.element.BlinkButton should call implicitly when user clicks BlinkButton, but it's not. 
I have to write it explicitly:
`android:onClick="fireEvent"` 
and

```
    public void fireEvent(View view) {
        fireEventButton.onClick(view);
    }
```

Why BlinkButton.onClick(); doesn't trigger automatically once user clicks button?

Comment: What does `HighLightButtonListener` do?

Comment: It just changes the color of a button.

Comment: Ok try it sfter adding `this.setOnClickListener(this);` after `this.setListener(new HighLightButtonListener());` line

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK That's exactly what I suggested in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Button` (or its superclasses) don't have an `onClick()` method by itself. The one you implement comes from the `View.OnClickListener` interface your Button class implements.

You never set your class' `OnClickListener`, and from your code it seems you want the `OnClickListener` to be the class itself, so your custom `Listeners` are actually called.

Add this line to the constructor:

```
setOnClickListener(this);
```

So it looks like this:

```
public BlinkButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setOnClickListener(this);
    this.setListener(new HighLightButtonListener());
}
```

You'll also have to remove the `onClick` xml attribute.

Answer (score 0):

BlinkButton class is only implementing the listener. If you look how View class handles clicks you'll find the following implementation:

```
public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener l) {
    if (!isClickable()) {
        setClickable(true);
    }
    getListenerInfo().mOnClickListener = l;
}
```

Basically there is no way to override a method and get the click events. You can set a listener from your class that will be called on click and that will further send the event to all listeners from your list.

```
public class BlinkButton extends Button implements View.OnClickListener {

    List<OnClickListener> onClickListenerList = new ArrayList<OnClickListener>();

    public BlinkButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setListener(new HighLightButtonListener());
        this.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for (OnClickListener listener : onClickListenerList) {
                    listener.onClick(this);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    //other constructors here 

    public void setListener(OnClickListener listener) {
        onClickListenerList.add(listener);
    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, the OP did not want to override a method and get the click events. The `onClick` method comes from the `OnClickListener` interface the class implements. The only thing that's still missing is setting the class to be its own OnClickListener as I show in my answer below.

Comment: You are assuming HighLightButtonListener implements OnClickListener and, even if it does, the other OnClickListeners from the list will not be called. The question was why onClick is not implicitly called and had to implement that workaround.

Comment: I'm assuming `HighLightButtonListener` implements OnClickListener (!= View.OnClickListener), but that's a valid assumption given `setListener()` takes an argument of that type. The other OnClickListeners will indeed be called. I did understand the question. What I am suggesting essentially does the same as your suggestion, except that I am proposing to use the things the OP has already implemented (make BlinkButton implement View.OnClickListener).